# epic browser no more Proxy at the far right of the address bar?

Tags: browser

In the [introduction page](https://www.epicbrowser.com/privacy/intro.html) shows the button will be at the right of the address bar, but after installing its version 40.0.2185.0, there is just a "star".

this picture shows what the address bar **should be**:

[image: here is the button i was talking about]

Comment: Which button are you talking about ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like just updated a picture

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the answer:

in settings there is an option after network setting:

[option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL6A6.png)

if true, why they hide it? and haven't change the introduction page?